# Mysql LEFT OUTER JOIN with LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my query

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`
 , `news`.`id` AS `t2_c0`
 , `news`.`title` AS `t2_c1`
 , `news`.`url` AS `t2_c2`
 , `news`.`date` AS `t2_c3`
 , `news`.`hash` AS `t2_c4`
 , `news`.`list_id` AS `t2_c5`
FROM
`words` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `words_news` `news_news`
ON (`t`.`id` = `news_news`.`word_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news` `news`
ON (`news`.`id` = `news_news`.`news_id`)
WHERE
  (`t`.`id` IN (8229, 8574, 7901))
```

and I need to select only 5 news from `news` table, but don't know how, how should I write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`
     , `news`.`id` AS `t2_c0`
     , `news`.`title` AS `t2_c1`
     , `news`.`url` AS `t2_c2`
     , `news`.`date` AS `t2_c3`
     , `news`.`hash` AS `t2_c4`
     , `news`.`list_id` AS `t2_c5`
FROM
  `words` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `words_news` `news_news`
ON (`t`.`id` = `news_news`.`word_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM `news` LIMIT 5) `news`
ON (`news`.`id` = `news_news`.`news_id`)
WHERE
  (`t`.`id` IN (8229, 8574, 7901));
```

or

```
SELECT `t`.`id` AS `t0_c0`
 , `news`.`id` AS `t2_c0`
 , `news`.`title` AS `t2_c1`
 , `news`.`url` AS `t2_c2`
 , `news`.`date` AS `t2_c3`
 , `news`.`hash` AS `t2_c4`
 , `news`.`list_id` AS `t2_c5`
FROM
  `words` `t`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `words_news` `news_news`
ON (`t`.`id` = `news_news`.`word_id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `news` `news`
ON (`news`.`id` = `news_news`.`news_id`)
JOIN (SELECT @var_ctr := 0) a
WHERE IF(`news`.`id` IS NOT NULL, @var_ctr := @var_ctr + 1, @var_ctr) <= 5
      AND (`t`.`id` IN (8229, 8574, 7901));
```

Comment: You missed AND  after"@var_ctr) <= 5" , but anyway it's selects only 1 word(with last id 7901) with 5 news, so i think we are pretty close to the right query! Thank's for helping!

Comment: this way you will get only 5 news with no null values. to get 5 records in output you need to put `LIMIT 5` at the end of query.